# Angular Routing : After lazy loading , page is redirecting to default route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have two modules in my angular 6 application one is app module and another one is User module, I am trying to implement lazy loading of the user module. Routing works if I manually hit the URL then the correct page from user module is getting displayed. But when I tried to navigate from header component it's not navigating to user page instead it's going to the default page.

Header.html

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" routerLink="/user/login">Login</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" routerLink="/user/register">Register</button>
    </form>
```

app-routing-module

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './components/welcome/welcome.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './components/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'welcome',
    component:WelcomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'user',
    loadChildren:'./user/user.module#UserModule'
  },
  {
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'welcome', 
    pathMatch: 'full' },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: PagenotfoundComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

User routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'register',
    component:RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path:'',
    redirectTo:'login',
    pathMatch:'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

App module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './components/welcome/welcome.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './components/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    PagenotfoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So when I click on the login button, I can see the login page but immediately it is redirecting to welcome page (http://localhost:4200/welcome)

Comment: can you share your app.module

Comment: App module updated above. thanks.

Comment: Can you try changing ``` path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome'``` to   path: '', redirectTo: 'login'.. Not sure is this is what you want..

Comment: No changing to login won't work. because loginComponent is part of another module

Comment: @DeepuNair can you create a stackblitz example reproducing this issue ?

Comment: @CruelEngine : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gdqrr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just mapped your `router-outlet` in the wrong component - please check that

I have tried your same scenario in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8whiw3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) please have a look

**app.component.html**

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" routerLink="/user/login">Login</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" routerLink="/user/register">Register</button>
    </form>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'welcome',
    component:HelloComponent
  },
  {
    path:'user',
    loadChildren:'./modules/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
  },
  {
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'welcome', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Everything worked as expected - please have a look to the link above - hope this helps you - Happy coding :)

**Update**

Finally it took much time to find the issue and solve it - but the issue seems to be tiny enough to eat our time :) - Yep the issue was a `button` tag with type as `submit` and that too wrapped inside a `form` tag - This cause the issue and makes the page to reload as it assumes that a form as been submitted and it renders the app `component` back

So first fix is in your `header.component.html` either remove your `form` tag or change your `button` type as `type="button"` if not change it to an `anchor` tag

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" [routerLink]="['user']">Login</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" routerLink="/user/register">Register</button>
      </form>
```

This will solve your issue completely - rest are the fixes need to be done based on your convenience

**app-routing.module.ts**

Don't bootstrap over here your bootstrap should only be on the `app.module` so your routing `@NgModule()` should be like this

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**user-routing.module.ts**

You need to export your `RouteModule` and read it from your `LazyModule` so your routing `@NgModule()` should be like this

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

That's all needed to fix everything and your code works perfectly - just feel free to share you concerns - cheers Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know soon.

Comment: I am getting error, I checked your code i have almost same code but still navigation is not working .  I tried to add code to stackblitz but getting some errorr So i pushed code my github account I know its too much of an ask but if you can have look at my repo that would be great.https://github.com/deepu105045/boyka

Comment: Thank you so much it just worked. That was a good lesson to learn.

Comment: No issues happy coding :)